# Javascript Convert primatives null, undefined and friends to string?

Tags: javascript

Is there a preferred or standard way to convert `null` to the empty string `""` but still have all other values be represented by their human readable string equivalent?

I would like to convert `undefined` to `""`, `null` to `""`, `0` to `"0"`, and `false` to `"false"` in the shortest way possible.

```
let val = null;

let a = String(val); console.log(a);
# "null"

let b = "" + val; console.log(b);
# "null"

let c = val? val: ""; console.log(c);
# undefined

val = 0;
let d = val ? val: ""; console.log(d);
# undefined

# current solution
function toStr(a) {
  if (a === null || a === undefined) {
    return "";
  }
  return String(a);
}
```

Comment: Your current solution looks fine.  If you're simply looking to golf it, you could use the conditional operator:  `return a === null || a === undefined ? '' : a + '';`